# Static Library created in VS2010 not linkeable in CVI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, c89, cvi

I created a simple static Ansi-C90 library with VS2010.
I was able to create a C++ project in VS2010, import and fully test the lib.

I opened a LabWindows CVI project and tried to import the lib file there.

Unfortunatelly there is not much to go on - the only message i get is:
"Bad header encountered while reading external module: 'Release\mylib.obj'"

Is there some way how i can investigate whats wrong with my lib file?
Is there some standard format that VS2010 is not following?

---

EDIT #1:

I identified a possible source of the problem but i am currently unable to check that.
VS2010 does not compiling as static-single-thread-libraries - that feature was removed.
It is possible that CVI can not handle static-multi-thread-libraries.

I also posted this question on the NI Forum.

EDIT #2:

NI Forum link was broken - i assume its NIs fault and provide a [Google Search](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy-ab&q=NI+Forum+%22CVI+can+not+link+VS2010+static+lib+files%22) Link for the posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [Mohan](http://forums.ni.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1296) in the NI Forums posted the answer there.

One option in visual studio needs to be changed so CVI can import the file:

`Properties` -> `General` -> `Whole Program Optimization`

Default is: "`Use Link Time Code Generation`"

Has to be changed to: "`No Whole Program Optimization`"